# Windows create undeletable file in shared folder

Tags: windows, security, ntfs, samba, cifs

I have a shared folder on a Windows 7 computer. 
I have two files in this folder. 
I want one file to be writable by other users from the network but I also want the other file to be **uchangeable** and **undeletable**.

How can I set this up in the windows security?

Answer (score 0):

Give write permissions to the share but set up the ACLs (Access Control Lists) for the files appropriately:

1. Right click on the desired file and click "Properties"
2. Click on the "Security" tab
3. Click the "Edit..." button
4. Set up the privileges as desired

You're going to want only the read attributes on the 'unchangeable' file and the Read & Write attributes on the writable one.

NOTE: To set permissions for everyone (say anyone can read the file), enter "Everyone" without quotes as the username.